# I need help--lists and Python

Tags: python, list, return

How to return a list in Python???

When I tried returning a list,I got an empty list.What's the reason???

Comment: i think you will get a better answer if you include the code you were using

Comment: No code?  That must be your problem.  To return a  list you need to actually write some code.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew commented, you will receive better answers if you show us the code you are currently using. Also if you could state what version of Python you are using that would be great.

There are a few ways you can return a list. Say for example we have a function called retlist.

```
def retlist():
    return []
```

will return the empty list

```
def retlist():
    a = list()
    a.append(5)
    return a
```

will return [5].

You can also use list comprehension to return a list

```
def retlist():
    return [x*x for x in range(10)]
```

There are plenty of ways to return a list. But basically it involves return .

If you are after a more detailed response, comment for what you need.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

to wit:

```
In [1]: def pants():
   ...:     return [1, 2, 'steve']
   ...: 
In [2]: pants()
Out[2]: [1, 2, 'steve']
```

Comment: And very worth a try! Wouldn't go anywhere without it :)